# Lagrange's original proof of Remainder Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, math-history

Where can I find Lagrange's original proof of the Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Which historical works have you consulted?

Comment: @user72694 Lagrange's Théorie des fonctions analytiques but I should have said I was hoping for a modern rendering. (I am French so that is not the difficulty.)

Answer (score 1):

See pages 440-450 Pringsheim: Pringsheim, A. 1900. "Zur Geschichte des Taylorschen Lehrsatzes." Bibl. math., (3)1(1900), 433-479.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do so ... when I can locate it. Hopefully, it will be at U of Penn. Just curious: how come you knew?

Comment: I found the reference in a book of the feu Grattan-Guinness.

Comment: I assume it is "The Development of the Foundations of Mathematical Analysis from Euler to Riemann". Does he discuss Lagrange's proof? (Haven't been able to get Pringsheim yet.)

Comment: No, he doesn't.  He also gives another reference by Brill and Noether from 1893.

Comment: Well then, it seems I am going to have to do it myself. (But Lagrange is nice to read if not always easy.) Thank you for the references.